# file I/O in xna windows phone.... reading and writing text data

Tags: c#, windows-phone

i wants to increment the score of player and check the highscore, so that i am storing score in text file.i am trying below code but it is throwing exception.

Exception : Value does not fall within the expected range.

```
public void storage()
{

    var appstorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    String filename = "store.txt";
    using (var file = appstorage.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            writer.Write(score);
        }

        using(var reader=new StreamReader(file)) 
        {
            playerscore =reader.ReadLine();

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure about windows phone support but in windows I would do it something like this

```
using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
    {
       writer.Write(score);
    }

    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
    {
        playerscore = reader.ReadInt32();
     }
}
```

Of course if you can only read an write text this would be the solution

```
using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,` FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(score.ToString());
    }

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        playerscore = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

    }
}
```